# Nvidia X Server Setting not opening

Tags: nvidia, 17.10

I installed 17.10 recently and went to change the graphics from the Nvidia card to the Intel card to save battery. After switching the Prime setting to use the Intel card, I can no longer open X server settings. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the program, but still nothing happens when I go to open it. Is this just an issue with 17.10 that will be fixed in later releases, like the upcoming 18.04?

Comment: Have you rebooted?

Comment: should I unintall, reboot, and then reinstall? I have rebooted

Comment: If you are logging into a wayland session then nvidia-settings cannot be opened. Log out & in to an xorg session

Comment: @doug -- How do we do that? Same problem, but in X11 after switching to Intel from nVidia and now can't open XServer nVidia Settings... perplexed.

Comment: @toszter, this thread was for 17.10 regarding it's deficiencies. Maybe run `nvidia-settings` from a terminal & see what it reports. Then start a new question, ect..

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 (running xfce, not that it matters). I fixed the problem. Here's the solution that worked for me. It went a little like this:

```
$ sudo prime-select nvidia
Info: the nvidia profile is already set
$ nvidia-settings
Error: nvidia driver is not loaded // Problem!
$ sudo prime-select intel
// Grub updates... some other configs are changed.
$ sudo prime-select nvidia
// Grub updates... configs are changed again.
// REBOOT.
$ nvidia-settings
// Et Viola! (Which means, and there it is.)
```

YMMV. Good luck out there. :)